# Как найти квадрат в двумерном массиве?

Tags: c++

Нашел задачу на двумерный массив и не понятно как код писать, сам недавно начал учит с++

### Есть файл квадрат.txt

В первой строке находиться количество строк и столбцов, а дальше элементы  двумерного массивa

[image: Есть файл квадрат.txt]

### Нужно найти самый большой квадрат

[image: Надо найти самый большой кводрат]
В теории выглядит так вроде: Чтение элементов с txt файла и дальше пойск

1. Начинается обход массива с левого верхнего элемента и проверяйется
   построчно , двигаясь слева на право.
2. Дальше проверяются  элементы с координатами (X, Y),(X+1, Y+1), (X,
   Y+1), (X+1, Y). Если все они равны единице, то  квадрат найден. В
   противном случае, массив не содержит квадрата.

Каким образом это можно реализовать в коде или  не правильно?

Comment: Вообще это стандартная задача. Используется двойной предпросчёт и скользящее окно. И да, это не самая простая задача. http://e-maxx.ru/algo/maximum_zero_submatrix

Comment: Используется двойной предпросчёт и скользящее окно всмысле?

Comment: читайте статью по ссылке. Мне кажется там написано лучше чем я сейчас это распишу.

Comment: Рекомендую отойти от компьютера и попробавать порассуждать с листочком бумаги и карандашом. Потом накидать код, откомпилить, получить миллион ошибок, исправить половину из них, а за второй половиной прийти сюда )

Comment: В массиве могут быть только единицы и нули? Квадрат только из единиц, или из нулей тоже интересует?

Comment: Приведенный вами алгоритм найдет только квадраты размера 2х2 из единиц. Вам точно нужно именно это? И главный вопрос: вы не можете написать на C++ или же составить алгоритм?

Comment: алгоритм именно не могу

Comment: @Momonga Можете вот на этот комментарий ответить: *"В массиве могут быть только единицы и нули? Квадрат только из единиц, или из нулей тоже интересует?"*? А то ответ я написал, но он - только для квадратов из единиц, и предполагается, что в остальных клетках - нули. Это правильно?

Comment: Да, Квадрат только из единиц, спасибо вам большое за ответ

Answer (score 4):

Задача нахождения максимального квадрата - элементарна. Просто строим вторую матрицу по правилу

```
A[i][j] = min(A[i - 1][j], A[i - 1][j - 1], A[i][j - 1]) + 1
```

Первая строка и первый столбец - копия исходной матрицы. Остальные элементы вычисляются по вышеприведенному правилу.

Максимальный элемент `A` обозначит правый нижний угол (и размер) максимального квадрата.

Comment: а почему максимум? Если у нас грубо говоря полоска единиц в виде `{0..0}1{0..0}` и так строк 50 то ответ будет 50 а не 1?

Comment: @pavel Ошибка. Да, конечно же нужен минимум, а не максимум.