# Помогите с задачей по с++

Tags: c++

Мое решение не проходит по ошибкам в  "Квадратик"

Ссылка https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=2774#1

По претестам и тестам которые сам задавал проходить но в отправление выходит ошибка "   Ошибка во время выполнения программы" и не исправить как бы не дебагл.

На клетчатом поле N×N, некоторые клетки которого закрашены, требуется найти размер максимального квадрата, состоящего из закрашенных клеток.

Входные данные
В первой строке входного файла содержится единственное целое число N (1≤N≤3000). В каждой из следующих N строк содержится по N символов «#» и «.» (соответствующих закрашенным и незакрашенным клеткам соответственно), описывающих таблицу.

Выходные данные
Выведите единственное целое число — максимальный размер полностью закрашенного квадрата.

'''

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
  
using namespace std;

const int mod = 998244353;
const int N=2e5+7;
const int INF=2e9+7;


  
int t;
char a[3007][3007];
int n,answer,b[3007][3007],c[3007][3007];
 
void solve(){
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            if (a[i][j]=='#'){
                int id=j;
                int ans=0;
                while(j<=n){
                    if (a[i][j]=='#') {
                        ans++;
                    }
                    else break;
                    j++;
                }
                for (int k=id;k<j;k++){
                    b[i][k]=ans;
                    ans--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if (a[i][j]=='#'){
                int ans=0;
                int id=i;
                while(i<=n){
                    if (a[i][j]=='#'){
                        ans++;
                    }
                    else break;
                    i++;
                }
                for (int k=id;k<i;k++){
                    c[k][j]=ans;
                    ans--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if (b[i][j]!=0){
                int id=i;
                int mn=INF;
                while(i<=n && b[i][j]!=0){
                    mn=min(mn,b[i][j]);
                    i++;
                }
                int mn1=INF;
                while(j<=n && c[i][j]!=0){
                    mn1=min(mn1,c[id][j]);
                    j++;
                }
                answer=max(answer,min(mn,mn1));
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<answer;       
} 
 
int main () {
   t=1;
   //cin>>t;  
   while(t--){
        solve();
   }   
} '''
```

Comment: А что у вас делается в коде? Он написан "по-олимпийски", обычному человеку трудно читать  и ориентироваться в этих однобуквенных обозначениях

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/maximum_zero_submatrix а что у вас по времени проходить не должно. всё же 3000 в кубе плюс операции не самые маленькие это много.

Comment: @pavel, вы сослались на другую задачу - для произвольного прямоугольника. Автор спрашивает про квадрат. В ней другая динамика - проще.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как найти квадрат в двумерном массиве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918517/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)